# Why is my program waiting for a thread that isn't joined?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

My program uses threading, but upon calling this certain function of another program (in a thread), the main program waits for the thread to end even though I haven't joined it, just started it.

main.py:

```
from constant_loops import Constant_loops
import threading

numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]


z = threading.Thread(target=Constant_loops().add_up(numbers))
z.start()

print("Thread has been finished")
```

constant_loops.py:

```
import random

class Constant_loops:

    def __init__(self):
        global counter
        counter = 0

    def generate_number(self):
        while True:
            result = random.randint(1,10)

            if result == 1 or result == 10:
                print("Desired number obtained")

                break

            else:
                print("Desired number hasn't been obtained yet")


        self.add_up(self.numbers)


    def add_up(self,  numbers):
        global counter
        self.numbers = numbers
        try:
            self.numbers[counter] += 1
            counter += 1
            self.generate_number()
        except:
            print("Finished one number")
```

I am aware that there are much simpler ways of doing given task. This is just a simple example of the problem Im having with my main program.

Comment: ``Thread(target=Constant_loops().add_up(numbers))`` completely evaluates ``Constant_loops().add_up(numbers)`` and assigns the *result* to ``target``. You must pass the callable itself to the Thread, e.g. as ``Thread(target=Constant_loops().add_up, args=(numbers,))``

Comment: and you have to add daemon=True like `threading.Thread(target=foo,daemon=True ...` the from https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon